# Bash for loop printing additional characters from jq output

Tags: bash, curl, jq

```
#!/bin/bash

DATA=$(curl -X GET https://$BASEURL/rest/api/latest/repos \
   -H "accept: application/json" \
   -H "authorization: Bearer $APIKEY" \
   | jq -c '[ .values[] | {project: .slug, repo: .project.key}] ')

echo $DATA
for repo in "${DATA[@]}"

do 
PROJ=$(jq -r '.[] | .project' <<< $repo)
REPO=$(jq -r '.[] | .repo' <<< $repo)

echo $PROJ
echo $REPO
done;
```

expected `$DATA` to be an array of objects with two properties `project, repo`

then I want to loop through each object in the `$DATA` array and extract the value for each property and store it in a variable.

then print the variables to stdout.

I can't figure out why `$repo` is another array. My understanding is using the syntax `"${array[@]}"` allows the variable `$repo` to reach into each index of the `DATA` array.

This brings me to why I'm tryin to parse that with jq in a subshell.  I thought I would be able to do something like `$repo["project"]` to extract the value but it's not working.

the output shows

```bash
# from echo $DATA, this seems to be correct.
[{"project": "some_proj_name", "repo": "repo_name" }, {...} ...]

# from for loop subshells 
# echo $PROJ 
some_proj_namepy
# echo $REPO
repo_nameaflsdkd
```

I have no idea where those extra characters are coming from

Comment: Re "expected $DATA to be an array of objects": Don't confuse JSON arrays and Bash arrays. You're just capturing a JSON-encoded string into a (scalar) Bash variable.

Comment: You have no bash arrays here at all. Even DATA isn't an array (so using `"${DATA[@]}"` to try to iterate over it is disingenuous).

Comment: If you wanted to load your content into an array, that would be `readarray -t data < <(curl ... | jq -c ...)`; _only then_ `"${data[@]}"` would be a sensible thing to do.

Comment: (and no, `${repo["project"]}` is inherently not a thing bash can do unless you load your object into an _associative_ array rather than the default numerically-indexed type -- and converting JSON into associative arrays is still more code you need to actually write, it's not something that happens "for free")

Comment: Following @CharlesDuffy's suggestion, make sure you don't produce one JSON-encoded array (`jq -c '[.values[] | …]'`) but a stream of JSON-encoded items: `jq -c '.values[] | …'` (i.e. without the capturing brackets).

Comment: cheers all, readarray worked a treat and i was able to get it going.

Comment: BTW, all-caps names are used for variables meaningful to the shell itself, whereas names with at least one lowercase character are reserved for application use and guaranteed not to have unintended changes on behavior of POSIX-specified tools; so it's best to stick to lowercase names for variables you're defining.